# Branch cut integral $\int_{-1}^1\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} d x$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

Define the branch of $f(z)=\left(1-z^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
by the branch cut $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty), f(0)=1$.

Use this branch and a suitably chosen semi-circular contour (with finite radius $R$ greater than 1) in the upper half plane to evaluate
$$
\int_{-1}^1\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} d x
$$

I am thinking of this contour[image]

where $\gamma_3,\gamma_4$ should cancel and $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ evaluates to $0$. I stuck at $\gamma_R$ since there seems to be no place to use the Residue theorem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is no singularity in the integrand you can't apply any kind of residue

Comment: @Masacroso then what contour should I use?

Comment: @ThetaOmega I don't know, to me the exercise doesn't make sense. The integral indeed is trivial with the substitution $x=\sin t$

Comment: There is no need to use the residue theorem.

Comment: @Masacroso One can apply the concept of the residue at infinity ... OR ... equivalently, one can use the approach I took in the solution posted herein. ;-)

Comment: @xpaul It's good to see you back now.  You are of course correct;  one not need to use contour integration.  But, if one chooses to do so, then the posted solution might be useful.  ;-)

Comment: @Masacroso: The integral is even easier if you recognize its geometric meaning of "What's the area of half of a circle with radius 1?"

Comment: @Dan The question is on the use of contour integration to evaluate the integral.  It is NOT simply "What is an easy way to evaluate the integral?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral over $\gamma_R$, $R>1$ can be evaluated by noting that $\int_0^\pi e^{i2\phi}\,d\phi = 0$ and that $\sqrt{1-z^2}=iz\sqrt{1-1/z^2}$ for the selected branch cuts and branch.  Therefore, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi&=\int_0^\pi \left(-R^2e^{i2\phi}\right)\sqrt{1-\frac1{R^2e^{i2\phi}}}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \left(-R^2e^{i2\phi}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2R^2e^{i2\phi}}+O\left(\frac1{R^4}\right)\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac\pi 2+O\left(\frac1{R^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to \infty$, we find that $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=\pi/2$.